# Schedualing toast notification with combobox in UWP

Tags: c#, mvvm, combobox, uwp

I code a Scheduling toast notification and i want that toast take its time from Combobox, i want help please

i use this code to start my app

```
(this.DataContext as AlertViewModel).Timer.Start();
```

this code i put in Button to start my app, and in combobox has times from TimeSpan in AlertViewModel.cs
binding in XAML

i want Scheduling toast notification use time from Combobox, i use MVVM method so i need help please

AlertViewModel Class:

```
 public class AlertViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public DispatcherTimer Timer { get; set; } = new DispatcherTimer();
    public List<TimeSpan> TimeOuts { get; set; } = new List<TimeSpan>();
    private TimeSpan timeOut;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private int selectedIndex;

    public int SelectedIndex
    {
        get {return selectedIndex;}
        set {selectedIndex = value; PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("SelectedIndex")); timeOut = TimeOuts[SelectedIndex];}
    }

    public List<Sound> Sounds { get; set; } = new List<Sound>();
    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> TimeUP;

    public AlertViewModel()
    {
        TimeOuts.Add(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5));
        TimeOuts.Add(new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0));                  // 10 Miuntes
        TimeOuts.Add(new TimeSpan(0, 15, 0));                  // 15 Miuntes
        TimeOuts.Add(new TimeSpan(0, 20, 0));                  // 20 Miuntes
        TimeOuts.Add(new TimeSpan(0, 30, 0));                  // 30 Miuntes
        TimeOuts.Add(new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0));                   // 1 Hour
        TimeOuts.Add(new TimeSpan(2, 0, 0));                   // 2 Hours
        TimeOuts.Add(new TimeSpan(6, 0, 0));                   // 6 Hours
        TimeOuts.Add(new TimeSpan(12, 0, 0));                  // 12 Hours

        timeOut = TimeOuts[SelectedIndex];

        Timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
        Timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;

        Sounds.Add(new Sound("Sound 1", "ms-appx:///Assets/Audio/sound1.mp3"));
        Sounds.Add(new Sound("Sound 2", "ms-appx:///Assets/Audio/sound2.mp3"));
    }

    private void Timer_Tick(object sender, object e)
    {
        timeOut = timeOut.Subtract(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1));
        if (timeOut.TotalSeconds == 0)
        {
            TimeUP(this, new EventArgs());
            timeOut = TimeOuts[SelectedIndex];
        }
    }
}
```

and my XAML Code:

```
<ComboBox
            x:Name="TimeCombobox"
            Margin="50,0"
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
            ItemsSource="{Binding TimeOuts}"
            SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectionChanged="TimeCombobox_SelectionChanged">
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource TimeSpanToStirngConverter}}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ComboBox>
```

Answer (score 1):

For scheduling toast notification, I'd suggest using [ScheduledToastNotification Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.notifications.scheduledtoastnotification). This is what we used to schedule a toast notification to appear at a specific time.

This class has two constructors. If you don't need snooze, you can use [ScheduledToastNotification(XmlDocument, DateTime)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.notifications.scheduledtoastnotification#Windows_UI_Notifications_ScheduledToastNotification__ctor_Windows_Data_Xml_Dom_XmlDocument_Windows_Foundation_DateTime_) constructor. This constructor has two parameters, the first one is the XML that defines the toast notification content and the second is the date and time that Windows should display the toast notification. And below is a simple sample shows a toast notification scheduled to display in 5 seconds.

```
string xml = @"
    <toast>
      <visual>
        <binding template='ToastGeneric'>
          <text>Microsoft Company Store</text>
          <text>New Halo game is back in stock!</text>
        </binding>
      </visual>
    </toast>";

var content = new Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument();
content.LoadXml(xml);

var deliveryTime = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddSeconds(5);

var toast = new ScheduledToastNotification(content, deliveryTime);

ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier().AddToSchedule(toast);
```

So there is no need to use `DispatcherTimer` in your code. You can just calculate the `deliveryTime` according to the selected `TimeSpan` of your `ComboBox` and then set it for the `ScheduledToastNotification`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. but i want this code var deliveryTime = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddSeconds(5); select his time its time from combobox, as many chooses in combobox

Comment: i make a loop with DispatcherTimer, if i use 5 miuntes from combobox, Sound 1 plays after every 5 miuntes :)